# How to reinstall truecrypt on the MBR?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, truecrypt, grub2

I've googled this so much and can't find the answer.

I had a dual booted system with a `TrueCrypt` encrypted Windows partition and a non encrypted Ubuntu partition (*accessed with GRUB2*) that was working great. But I accidentally triggered GRUB to overwrite the MBR. 
Now my computer boots directly into GRUB and I can't access Windows!

If there is a way of reinstalling TrueCrypt so that it asks for password to enter into Windows and lets me press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to boot Ubuntu from GRUB2 then please let me know.

Note: I'd rather not have to decrypt the Windows partition.

Comment: Please don't spam your youtube channel.

Comment: Yes. You can use your Linux to do it. From your Linux, you can use TrueCrypt for Linux to both access your encrypted data and re-install the bootloader. For dual-boot, I did it before but forgot the exact steps as I'm now using something else (DiskCryptor). Roughly, TC boot-loader was installed on MBR, and GRUB on the /boot partition. Also, I strongly advise to make the BL back-up (burn the .iso file) & headers back up of your TC partitions.

Answer (score 0):

From the TrueCrypt [encryption scheme](http://andryou.com/truecrypt/docs/encryption-scheme.php), system volume header resides at the end of the volume, and should still be there, even if you have overwritten the boot loader.

> The first 512 bytes of the volume (i.e., the standard volume header)
>   are read into RAM, out of which the first 64 bytes are the salt (see
>   TrueCrypt Volume Format Specification). For system encryption (see the
>   chapter System Encryption), the last 512 bytes of the first logical
>   drive track are read into RAM (the TrueCrypt Boot Loader is stored in
>   the first track of the system drive and/or on the TrueCrypt Rescue
>   Disk)

What this means is, your data should still be accessible. If you boot into another system with TrueCrypt installed (you can use your Linux, there is a [TrueCrypt version for Linux](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm) as well), you could mount your partition and access the data. Note that you have to toggle the "system volume" option when mounting. I suggest you test first that your data is intact, and once you're able to access it, **make a backup of the volume's header**. This is very important to have, because if the header is lost / corrupt, it practically means your data is lost forever!

Now that you're safe, you should be able to re-install the boot-loader by using TrueCrypt from your Linux and configure it as you did before. **Make sure to burn the .iso back-up to a CD/DVD this time**, as it will let you use the media to boot into your Windows, in case you overwrite the BL again. I'm unable to find documentation for the boot loader, but I remember it was simple to set-up to work with Linux. The boot-loader should be installed on the MBR, and GRUB installed on some primary partition (/boot, let's say). The TC boot-loader should then be configured to try boot other partitions if ESC is pushed, in effect giving control to GRUB when it finds it at the beggining of the partition where you installed it to.

If my memory serves me well, TC will make a back-up of the original boot-loader but can't remember if there was a setting that lets you boot the original one once ESC is pushed. This could also work, without having to install GRUB on the partition.

I'm sorry I can't provide the detailed steps for the multi-boot set-up, it's been a while since I experimented with it, but this should give you some guidelines to start with.